# Cannot see main user profile directory on old vista hdd on win7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-vista

I have an old laptop HDD that ran Vista that I need to get some pictures and movies off of. I've attached it via SATA cable to my new Win 7 (64 bit) machine and it mounts fine, except I can't see the main user profile in the D:\Users directory. I've changed ownership and permissions for the D: drive to my C:\ Username but still no luck. I read something about it being caused by the UAC being active on the Vista machine. Is this true? Is there a way to disable this and gain access to the main profile without putting it back into the old laptop (it's fried and won't boot)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if user folder does not use EFS - Encryption on directory/file level. You have to disable it by logging in to that system and right clicking on encrypted directory. It would probably have a different name color.
2. Try to select user folder and change permission and ownership to Everyone also selecting an option to cascade/propagate this action in subfolders.

Answer (score -3):

You can try to access the folder through a boot/recovery CD/USB, then copy the folder somewhere else in order to use it.

A link on how to create boot USB:
https://rufus.akeo.ie/?locale=en_US

Comment: @Burgi While not of high quality, this is a legitimate *attempt* to answer the question as it offers a method by which to access the folder in question. As such, it would be better to downvote if found unhelpful rather than flagging it for potential deletion.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail on how to do this?  If you link to any source material, please be sure to include the essential parts of the linked material here to keep your answer useful even if/when the links break.

Comment: Low quality content shouldn’t be kept around it should either be improved upon or deleted.